# Bottom 2 rows of a data frame are not getting displayed on a stacked bar chart using matplotlib

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

The values in bottom 2 rows - across 2 columns of a data frame are not getting recognized by the plot function and not getting displayed.  It worked in another place in my notebook, with much larger numbers of rows and columns, but here it is not.

df:

```
       Total    Indigenous  Imported
2013    187     0           0
2014    667     0           0
2015    188     0           0
2016    85      0           0
2017    122     0           0
2018    0       169.2       199
2019    0       681         421
```

```
color3 = ['black', 'magenta', 'gold']

df.plot.bar(stacked=True, colors = color3, legend=False)
plt.legend(title='States', loc="right", ncol=4, bbox_to_anchor=(3, 0, 0.5, 1))
plt.title('Origins of Measles in 2018 & 2019', color ="black",  size=15)
plt.xlabel("Years")
plt.ylabel("Reported Cases", size=15)
plt.xticks(size=10)
plt.yticks(size=10)
plt.savefig("breakdown.png", bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

[image: what actually appears]

Comment: Same code is working for me try to change the color

Comment: This is working for me as well. Check the value of df before plotting.

Comment: Big thanks to everyone who replied and confirmed.  I had fixed the problem by noticing that the numbers in the last 2 rows containing info for 2018 and 2019 of the imported CSV file were strings and not 'float' nor 'int'. After I posted this question, I continued researching and used .keys() to examine the contents of the columns, I discovered it.  Nevertheless, thank you all.